# Include proto file in NodejsFunction constructs target bundle

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk, esbuild

I have a lambda function that is supposed to return a serialized protocol buffer payload. For that I need the `myobject.proto` in the same directory as the lambda handler.

For the function itself I use the AWS CDK construct `NodejsFunction`.

```js
new NodejsFunction(this, 'LambdaThatCreatesProtobufPayload', {
    entry: './src/lambda/handlers/LambdaThatCreatesProtobufPayload.ts',
    handler: 'handler',
    bundling: {
        minify: true,
    }
});
```

How can I include the proto file in the resulting bundle or provide it to the lambda function?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to bundle a file like the `myobject.proto` with the [Esbuild file loader](https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#external-file).

Configure the bundler to use the file loader for files with .proto.

```js
new NodejsFunction(this, 'LambdaThatCreatesProtobufPayload', {
    entry: './src/lambda/handlers/LambdaThatCreatesProtobufPayload.ts',
    handler: 'handler',
    bundling: {
        minify: true,
        loader:  { '.proto': 'file' }
    }
});
```

Then require the file inside the handler.

```js
const pathToProto = require('./myobject.proto')
```

The bundled file has a different filename. Therefore `pathToProto` contains the path with the new filename:

> ./myobject-55DNWN2R.proto

This results in a deployed lambda with the proto file and handler file in the same directory.